# Getting a key error due to having a dash sign in string

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to go through a lot of data files and selecting specific values that meet some cuts I designate. A lot of the the files have dashes in them, ie `COSMOS-125`. I think python is thinking I am trying to do a minus sign instead of just a string dash.

```py
cuts = '(Redshift>0.9) & (Redshift<1.5) & ((Redshift_Quality==3)|(Redshift_Quality==4)) & (D4000>1.4) & (member>0) & ((Cluster != COSMOS-125)|(Cluster != COSMOS-221)|(Cluster !=COSMOS-28)\
|(Cluster != COSMOS-63)|(Cluster !=SXDF49)|(Cluster !=SXDF64)|(Cluster !=SXDF76)|(Cluster !=SpARCS1033)|(Cluster !=SpARCS0034)|(Cluster !=SpARCS0036)|(Cluster !=SpARCS0215)|(Cluster !=SpARCS1047)|\
(Cluster !=SpARCS1613))'
```

The cluster cut is basically saying 'ignore all these clusters' but I keep getting an error:

> "key error 'COSMOS'"
>
> "Undefinedvariableerror: name 'COSMOS' is not defined"

I know that just `COSMOS` is not defined because there are numerous `COSMOS` files but I think it is ignoring the `-125`, `-221`, etc.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what you're doing here and how, but you could try to put filenames between quotation marks, like this:

```
cuts = '(Redshift>0.9) & (Redshift<1.5) & ((Redshift_Quality==3)|(Redshift_Quality==4)) & (D4000>1.4) & (member>0) & ((Cluster != "COSMOS-125")|(Cluster != "COSMOS-221")|(Cluster !="COSMOS-28")\
|(Cluster != "COSMOS-63")|(Cluster != "SXDF49")|(Cluster != "SXDF64")|(Cluster != "SXDF76" )|(Cluster != "SpARCS1033")|(Cluster != "SpARCS0034")|(Cluster != "SpARCS0036")|(Cluster != "SpARCS0215")|(Cluster != "SpARCS1047")|\
(Cluster != "SpARCS1613"))'
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the function that actually performed the cuts. But your solution worked though! Thank you!